# Sort CSV file by multiple columns using the "sort" command

Tags: csv, sorting, unix

I have a CSV-like file, and I would like to sort it by column priority, like ["ORDER BY" in SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html). For example, given the following rows,

```
3;1;2
1;3;2
1;2;3
2;3;1
2;1;3
3;2;1
```

If "ORDER BY" were `column2, column1, column3`, the result would be:

```
2;1;3
3;1;2
1;2;3
3;2;1
1;3;2
2;3;1
```

I'd like to know how to get this same result using the `sort` command on Unix.

Comment: By the way, that's an ssv file (semicolon separated values) :P

Comment: Sadly, `sort` is an unreliable foundation in the real world where quotation happens to be

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on UNIX.SE and is a dupe of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52762/trying-to-sort-on-two-fields-second-then-first

Answer (score 198, accepted):

You need to use two options for the `sort` command:

- `--field-separator` (or `-t`)
- `--key=<start,end>` (or `-k`), to specify the sort key, i.e. which range of columns (start through end index) to sort by. Since you want to sort on 3 columns, you'll need to specify `-k` 3 times, for columns `2,2`, `1,1`, and `3,3`.

To put it all together,

```
sort -t ';' -k 2,2 -k 1,1 -k 3,3
```

Note that `sort` can't handle the situation in which fields contain the separator, even if it's escaped or quoted.

Also note: this is an old question, which belongs on UNIX.SE, and was [also asked there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52762/trying-to-sort-on-two-fields-second-then-first) a year later.

---

Old answer: depending on your system's version of `sort`, the following might also work:

```
sort --field-separator=';' --key=2,1,3
```

Or, you might get "stray character in field spec".

According to the [sort manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html), if you don't specify the end column of the sort key, it defaults to the end of the line.

Comment: @Charlie Martin:this would not work for csvs that contain ";" within the cell, right?

Comment: Right.  You could work out something trating the land and right hand sides of those as separate fields.  If that doesn't work, look at using tr to turn the semicolons into tabs and maybe use column numbers.

Comment: If the values are numeric, then you probably want consider using the `-n` option which will "compare according to string numerical value" or the `-g` option which will "compare according to general numerical value". A string comparison of numeric values will get the numbers ordered like `1,10,2,20`. At least those are options available on my version of sort on CentOS. You should verify with the man page what the correct options are on your version of sort.

Comment: I get `sort: stray character in field spec: invalid field specification ‘2,1,3’`

Comment: However, `sort --field-separator=',' -r -k3 -k1 -k2 source.csv > target.csv` worked for me.

Comment: Moose, can you tell us what system you're using?  Various implementations of sort have little differences.

Comment: this would never work for a real csv files that contain field separator within the column

Comment: Oddly, that doesn't appear to be the question that was asked, now does it?

Comment: @CharlieMartin: Ubuntu 14.10. I use `/usr/bin/sort`. According to `sort --version` it is `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.23`

Comment: Well, see? What I have worked on Mac OS/X -- essentially BSD -- at the time I wrote the answer. Always read the fine man page.

Comment: how long would this take on a 500MB csv file?

Comment: Depends on your system. I would imagine tens of minutes, wouldn't be surprised at hours.

Comment: I just sorted a 6GB file in minutes - I believe `sort` is highly optimized, also for sorting large files that do not fit in RAM.

Comment: @MartinThoma it's been a long time but I ran into your problem and I found that `sort --field-separator=';' --key={2,1,3}`. This worked in `GNU coreutils 8.4` from April 2016

Comment: @mrbolichi the notation `--key={2,1,3}` uses brace expansion of bash

Comment: @mrbolichi that might have appeared to work, but is incorrect. I've edited the answer to explain that `-k` expects the start **and end** column indexes. Also note how Martin changed the column order [in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471101/sort-csv-file-by-multiple-columns-using-the-sort-command#comment39595676_9471139) from the original `2,1,3` to `3,1,2`. That is also incorrect.

Answer (score 38):

Suppose you have another row `3;10;3` in your `unsorted.csv` file. Then I guess you expect a numerically sorted result:

```
2;1;3
3;1;2
1;2;3
3;2;1
1;3;2
2;3;1
3;10;3
```

and not an alphabetically sorted one:

```
2;1;3
3;1;2
3;10;3
1;2;3
3;2;1
1;3;2
2;3;1
```

To get that, you have to use `-n`:

```
sort --field-separator=';' -n -k 2,2 -k 1,1 -k 3,3 unsorted.csv
```

It is worth mentioning that `2,2` has to be used. If only `2` is used, then `sort` takes the string from beginning of field 2 to the end. `2,2` makes sure that only field `2` is used.

Comment: The pointer as to the difference between -k 2, and -k 2,2 is significant!  I had overlooked this on my first reading of the man page.  Thanks.

Comment: I added a few extra rows, `3;10;3` , `3:10:5` , `3:10;2`, `3;10;3` in that order in the source file, and when using _just_ `-k 2,2` it appears to sort on column 2 and 3. The man page says `"The -k option may be specified multiple times, in which case subsequent keys are compared when earlier keys compare equal."`. In my case the earlier key (value=10) did compare equal, however, I didn't specify `-k` multiple times. I'm not sure if this is reliable behaviour, or related to my system (mac). Ultimately it doesn't matter though, as long as the primary sorting is correct.

Comment: Oh I see there is also `-s` stable sort which ignores the equal keys, that is apparently faster according to man.

Answer (score 27):

Charlie's answer above didn't work for me on Cygwin (sort version 2.0, GNU textutils), the following did:

```
sort -t"," -k2 -k1 -k1
```

Comment: Cygwin has an older version of sort.  As always, the man page is your friend.

Comment: I agree with @CharlieMartin, you should check the man page on your system. On CentOS I used `sort --field-separator=';' -k2 -k1 -k3 test.csv`