# PHP Sort large csv file

Tags: php, csv

What is the best way to sort large `csv` files in php, up to 5GB ?
Should I use some `CSVReader` or use unix commands?

Comment: easy with unix coreutils

Comment: How often do you need to sort and is it dependent on user input?

Comment: @Sam Kool 5 times / minute

Comment: The problem is that I have large CSV file and i need to use it for CRUD page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP pages are usually made for processing quick web pages for browsers, for a file in GB and to not keep crashing into memory and time limits, call a unix command independently.

Here is a good reference to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/222445/6288442

> " > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &"
>
> That will redirect both stdio (first >) and stderr (2>) to /dev/null
>   and run in the background.
>
> There are other ways to do the same thing, but this is the simplest to
>   read.
>
> An alternative to the above double-redirect:
>
> " &> /dev/null &"

and https://stackoverflow.com/a/223745/6288442

> ```
> `echo "the command"|at now`;
> ```

As for the sort command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9471139/6288442

> sort --field-separator=';' --key=2,1,3

Comment: performance using a unix command is usually always better since it runs directly on the shell as opposed to running over the php interpreter which is an extension on the web server you are using