# Sorting csv file based on column 2 only. if 2 rows of column 2 are same, should be input file order only. should not sort based on any other column

Tags: shell, csv, unix, awk

I have seen lot of posts on sorting a file based on a column but didn't help me.

I want to sort a CSV file based on column 2 only.

for example : The data in my file looks like below

```
H1,H2,H3,H4
C11,R_G,S_F_G,22-OCT-2019
C12,R_G,S_F_G,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E_RA,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E_RB,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E_RA,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E_RB,22-OCT-2019
```

Expected sorting order of column 2 like below

```
H1,H2,H3,H4
C13,R_E,S_F_E,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E_RA,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E_RB,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E_RA,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E_RB,22-OCT-2019
C11,R_G,S_F_G,22-OCT-2019
C12,R_G,S_F_G,22-OCT-2019
```

I tried to sort with below command

```
awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 {print $0 | "sort -t, -k2"}' inputfile >> outputfile
```

The result is like below

```
H1,H2,H3,H4
C13,R_E,S_F_E,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E_RA,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E_RA,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E_RB,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E_RB,22-OCT-2019
C11,R_G,S_F_G,22-OCT-2019
C12,R_G,S_F_G,22-OCT-2019
```

If you observe the result, column 2 and column 3 is getting sorted, but I want only column 2 to be sorted and if the column 2 is same for 2 rows it should be in the order of appearance in the input file.

it will be great if anyone can help me to understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort CSV file by column priority using the "sort" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471101/sort-csv-file-by-column-priority-using-the-sort-command)

Comment: The answer of glen Jackman is fantastic https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/345076/273492

Comment: ts not duplicate @RaviSaroch I am expecting to sort only based on column 2. If 2 rows in column 2 are same, it should be in the order of appearance in the input file. I already tried the solution which you referred. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Raj do you have seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59041272/757714 ? Is it not ok? Why? Thank you

Comment: @aborruso I will not be able to install because of admin restrictions. and even if i install in my dev machine after getting approval, installing it in my production server is a big job because of lot of approval process involved in it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --csv sort -f H2 input.csv
```

you will have

```
H1,H2,H3,H4
C13,R_E,S_F_E,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E_RA,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E_RB,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E_RA,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E_RB,22-OCT-2019
C11,R_G,S_F_G,22-OCT-2019
C12,R_G,S_F_G,22-OCT-2019
```

Comment: "mlr" is not recognized.  it looks like i have to install/configure Miller project. If yes, I need to go through lot of approval process @aborruso. Can you please let me know id the same can be achieved with awk/some other regular command. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Raj Miller is is awk, sed, cut, join, and sort for name-indexed data such as CSV, TSV, and tabular JSON. Install it is very easy http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/build.html#Prebuilt_executables

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `head`, `tail` and `sort`, e.g.

```
head -n1 file; tail -n+2 file | sort -t, -k2
```

Where the use of `head -n1 file` simply outputs the header, then the remaining lines obtained with `tail -n+2 file` are piped to `sort -t, -k2` for sorting with the result being the complete sorted file with heading.

To create a new file containing the sorted results, run the command line in a subshell and redirect the output to a new file, e.g.

```
(head -n1 file; tail -n+2 file | sort -t, -k2) > sortedfile
```

(you can then use the 2-step of `rm file; mv sortedfile file` to replace the original with the sorted file if you like)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ head -n1 file; tail -n+2 file | sort -t, -k2
H1,H2,H3,H4
C13,R_E,S_F_E,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E_RA,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E_RA,22-OCT-2019
C13,R_E,S_F_E_RB,22-OCT-2019
C14,R_E,S_F_E_RB,22-OCT-2019
C11,R_G,S_F_G,22-OCT-2019
C12,R_G,S_F_G,22-OCT-2019
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @David Rankin.  I am expecting to sort only based on column 2. If 2 rows in column 2 are same, it should be in the order of appearance in the input file. If you observe the results you posted, when column 2 is same, it is sorted based on column 1/3. but I want it to be same order as input file. Please observe Expected Results which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I see what you are saying. That may take a manual sort since even with the `awk` `sort` or the `sort` with shell, there is very little control over the algorithm used. You would almost need a bubble or insertion sort. I'll have time in an hour or two to look at it further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
sort --field-separator=',' --key=2 filename
```

--field-separator=',' => field separator is ","

--key=2 or -k 2 : sorting a data on the basis of second column number

Comment: Thanks for your time @RaviSaroch .I am expecting to sort only based on column 2. If 2 rows in column 2 are same, it should be in the order of appearance in the input file. I already tried the solution which you referred.  If you observe the results you posted, when column 2 is same, it is sorted based on column 1/3. but I want it to be same order as input file. Please observe Expected Results which I mentioned in the question