# how to use pre-commit hook to sort a csv file

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I have a `.csv` file that I'd like to sort pre-commit. I [found](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks/issues/357) this pre-commit hook `file-contents-sorter` which sorts the file with the first value.

```
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
    rev: v2.1.0
    hooks:
       - id: file-contents-sorter
         files: blackbox-files\.csv$
```

But I'd like to sort it first by the last value and then the first value. I was wondering if I can do something like this with pre-commit git hooks.

My csv file is something like this:

```
aaaa,bbbb
sssss,bbbb
fff,bbb
kkkk,eeee
www,ddd

The above code gives me this output:

aaaa,bbbb
fff,bbb
kkkk,eeee
sssss,bbbb
www,ddd

I'd like this output:

aaaa,bbbb
fff,bbb
sssss,bbbb
www,ddd
kkkk,eeee
```

Comment: you'll need to write a tool to do your specific sort, `file-contents-sorter` is intentionally simplistic and does not implement a csv parser.  asking for tool suggestions on SO is off topic as it tends to invite spammy/advertisery answers

Answer (score 0):

Based on [a simple hack](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1728#issuecomment-741726739) and [`sort`'s ability to sort by arbitrary columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9471139/96588), here's [how you can do this using GNU `sort`](https://gitlab.com/engmark/tilde/-/blob/6e84274ece333a440a34de673e90ba9d283485fd/.pre-commit-config.yaml#L101-112):

```
  - id: sort
    name: Sort records
    entry: bash
    args:
      [
        -c,
        'for index in $(seq 0 "$#"); do LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8 sort
        --field-separator=, --key=2,2 --key=1,1
        --output="${!index}" "${!index}"; done',
      ]
    files: blackbox-files\.csv$
    language: system
```

Basically, since `sort` can only sort one file at a time in-place we have to loop over the entire parameter array (not `$@`, because that doesn't include `$0`). `LC_COLLATE` sets the locale for collation or sorting, to make sure the sorting is consistent on different machines. And most of the `sort` arguments are there to sort by the second and then the first comma-separated field.

Answer (score -1):

There's an open question here, you've got `bbb` sorting both before and after `bbbb`, simplest explanation for that is the first field overrides the second, but you've also got `kkkk,eeee` sorting after `www,ddd`, simplest explanation for that is the second field overrides the first. Maybe I'm just blindspotting here, and it's kind of a side issue so I'm going to just make something up that produces the results you gave and go with it. The sort keys I use do that but might not do what you want all the time, check those.

The normal-ish way to clean up a file on the way in to the repo is with a filter. To get the results you show

```
git config filter.blackbox.clean 'sort -k2.1,2.1 -k1 -t,'
git config filter.blackbox.smudge cat
```

and

```
echo blackbox-files.txt filter=blackbox >>.gitattributes
```

then the file will be filtered on add. The filter specs themselves have to be (re)configured in any repo that uses them, this is a gross infelicity forced by the need to not invite code-injection attacks, sorry but ILOVEYOU was not fun. Make a note in your README, or add a couple lines in your setup recipe, however you do your new-repo onboarding this is another annoying step.